# i2c transfer from gpio int handler fails on imx6sx cortex m4 side

Tags: c, interrupt, i2c, interrupt-handling, cortex-m

i'm experiencing something that bugs me for days, so i am working on the imx6sx cortex m4 side, i have a sensor connected to one of the i2c buses, sensor is set up with data ready on INT1 which is connected to one of the gpios from the MCU. After boot, i configure the sensor so that it outputs data ready interrupt. Note that the i2c works also in interrupt mode, so if i try to read the sensor when the data ready line is asserted i have to wait in the GPIO INT Handler until the i2c transfer is complete in order to get another data ready int and so on.

My problem is that i don't want to wait in the GPIO INT Handler until the i2c transfer is complete, that's why i made the i2c on interrupts too, but if i don't wait in the GPIO Int Handler, something happens to the i2c because the sensor it's not ack the transfer, so i'n not getting other data-ready interrupts.

Please help if you have any idea what could be wrong, also the i2c bus Interrupt has a higher priority than the GPIO interrupt, and unfortunately i can't use a debugger for debugging, only the old-fashioned way, printfs in the console

Thanks

Comment: We are no clairvoyants. See [ask].

Comment: This question is properly asked.

Answer (score 1):

You could use INT1 to trigger a lower priority software interrupt to handle the i2c, then exit freeing the interrupt.

Consider using a RTOS to manage this for you.